# Is a higher concentration of fuel system cleaner bad?

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-tank, fuel-additives

In my case I used Gumout. On the back of the bottle it says this:

> Add entire bottle to nearly empty gasoline tank at time of oil change.
>   Refill tank with 18 to 35 gallons of gasoline. Do not refill tank
>   until near empty. Repeat every 3,000 miles at time of oil change.

So, this is what I did:

(1) CHANGE OIL

(2) SWAP IN NEW OIL FILTER

(3) POUR GUMOUT INTO GAS TANK

(4) DRIVE TO GAS STATION WITH NEARLY EMPTY TANK WITH GUMOUT IN TANK

(5) TOP OFF (20 GALLONS OF 87)

I'm just wondering if my drive to the gas station should have come before I added the fuel cleaner because if there was a gallon in the tank with the additive mixed in, then the concentration was very high compared to the lower limit of 18 gallons. Is a higher concentration of fuel additives bad?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It would be helpful to know how far away the fuel station is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I use a similar stuff but it goes in with each tankful and I do this at the pump...

For your situation probably nothing will happen except that some of the product was consumed too fast ie at a higher concentration...

Use it now as directed and fill up again when close to empty - should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Its more effective in a lower volume of fuel than higher-no damage doen, it will just be less effective in more fuel

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  filling the tank will dilute the cleaning additive so that it's significantly less effective. I use Sea Foam on motorcycles that have varnish deposits clogging the carbs. I remove, disassemble, and clean by hand and ultrasonic cleaning machine, then install carburetor kits if required.  After reassembling and installation I'll do some fuel treatment  I mix at 50% Sea Foam, 50% fuel (up to .5 gallons).  The particular bike will not run very well and will smoke (white) until the mixture is gone.  Then I'll put 100% Fuel to see if it needs more mixture, or the carbs removed and more work done.  But most of the time, the bike will run much better at this point and just need pilot needles adjusted and synchronizing in the case of multiple carbs.  Once you have taken care of your fuel system problems, I suggest switching your fuel to Chevron or Texaco, both contain Techron an additive designed to clean (carbon deposits, etc) and maintain the fuel system.  I used to think it was a gimmick to sell gas until I disassembled an old high mileage motorcycle engine that had been run exclusively on Chevron Fuel. I was amazed how clean that motor was.  Anyway, Good luck! Here's a link for more info on Techron:   https://www.techron.com